# DOM Text Node Manipulation With Javascript Treewalker Issue

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

So i am trying to select ALL the 'TEXT NODES' on the HTML page using Javascript Treewalker. Basically i want to change the color of ALL the "vowels" on the "ENTIRE" web page to red. That is "a,e,i,o,u" ANYWHERE on the page should be red in color.

I created a Treewalker object with the standard procedure to filter only TEXT NODES.

Here is my HTML code

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>TREEWALKER</h1>
        <p>Treewalker demo example. We'll see how Treewalker works in Javascript by creating one and filtering all DOM nodes which are Text Nodes.
        Then we'll replace all the vowels with red color.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>T</li>
            <li>R</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="Treewalker.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
let body = document.body;

const treewalker = document.createTreeWalker(body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
    acceptNode: (node) => {
        return (node.nodeValue.trim() !== '') ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    }
});


while(treewalker.nextNode()) {
    treewalker.currentNode.textContent = treewalker.currentNode.textContent.replace(/e/gi, '<span>e</span>');
    treewalker.currentNode.parentElement.innerHTML = treewalker.currentNode.textContent
}
```

My problem starts here:

```
while(treewalker.nextNode()) {
    treewalker.currentNode.textContent = treewalker.currentNode.textContent.replace(/e/gi, '<span style='color:red'>e</span>');
    treewalker.currentNode.parentElement.innerHTML = treewalker.currentNode.textContent
```

This code should cycle through ALL TEXT NODES and replace the 'e' inside them with the span tag.

It does that BUT STOPS after changing the 'e' in the

```
<h1>TREEWALKER</h1>
```

tag ONLY.
It doesn't go beyond that. I have failed to understand why.

Comment: Because by setting `innerHTML`, you've just removed the element that the tree walker was pointing to from the DOM.

Comment: don't prune the branch you're sitting on... it would be better to push everything into an array, then make your mods from the array instead of a collection

Comment: I think the mistake you're making is conflating text nodes with Elements. Text nodes are, by definition, purely text. You can't change the color of singular aspects of them. You need to either decide to replace them with HTMLElement nodes or overlay them. You can change the parent element, however, because you're altering a child Text node, styling applies to all text within said element - not just the text node(or part of the text node) you're wanting it to. This is unfortunately kind of a waste of time to approach it as you are, because that isn't how markup or the DOM were designed to work.